# Are there any log file about Windows Services Status?

Tags: windows-services, logging

I want to figure out when the services was start up and terminated. Are there any kind log file about it?

Comment: could be programming related if OP needs to add code to a service to enable logging.

Comment: or may its his own service :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Take a look at the `System` log in Windows EventViewer (`eventvwr` from the command line).
You should see entries with source as 'Service Control Manager'. e.g. on my WinXP machine,

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   Service Control Manager
Event Category: None
Event ID:   7036
Date:       7/1/2009
Time:       12:09:43 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MyMachine
Description:
The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service entered the running state.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: If only it would also show the source of the command to the SC. ☹

Comment: What does N/A under User mean?

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case ADAM service was not starting due to an incorrect password. I have managed to find the root cause only through EventViewer

Comment: Still relevant on Win Server 2019

Answer (score 86):

Under Windows 7, open the Event Viewer. You can do this the way Gishu suggested for XP, typing `eventvwr` from the command line, or by opening the **Control Panel**, selecting **System and Security**, then **Administrative Tools** and finally **Event Viewer**. It may require UAC approval or an admin password.

In the left pane, expand **Windows Logs** and then **System**. You can filter the logs with **Filter Current Log...** from the Actions pane on the right and selecting "Service Control Manager." Or, depending on why you want this information, you might just need to look through the Error entries.

[image]

The actual log entry pane (not shown) is pretty user-friendly and self-explanatory. You'll be looking for messages like the following:

> "The Praxco Assistant service entered the stopped state."
>   "The Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service entered the running state."
>   "The MySQL service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 3 time(s)."

Comment: how do you raise the verbosity or loglevel? the current verbosity of these messages is a joke.

Comment: Under "Event level" you ought to be able to select "Critical" for less info or any of the other options for more info. Your guess is as good as mine as to why they ordered them up-and-down before left-and-right.

Comment: For Windows 8 and 10, these events are not available anymore as per https://superuser.com/questions/1300506/event-id-7036-not-showing-in-windows-event-log-on-win10

Answer (score 7):

Through the Computer management console, navigate through Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System. Every services that change state will be logged here.

You'll see info like:
*The XXXX service entered the running state* or *The XXXX service entered the stopped state*, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely place to find this sort of information is in the event viewer (under Administrative tools in XP or run eventvwr)  This is where most services log warnings errors etc.